# Can we have NOT condition in url-mapping for servlet-filter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Is is possible to have NOT condition as a value for url-mapping for servlet-filter?
Ex:
I want to filter all the requests that does not contain "." so lets consider I have a request like www.website.com/pages. This does not contain "." or ".html" so I want to filter all such request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You can add this condition in your filter and do just `chain.doFilter(req, resp)` (i.e. skip the filter).

Comment: But in this case every request has an overhead to go through the filter resulting in degradation in performance. Is there any other alternative you can think of?

Comment: It will have to pass through a check anyway. It will just be out of your control ;)